# Proving that element does not exist in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to prove that $\frac{1}{3}\notin \left\{\frac{y}{2^x}:x,y\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$.

Let's assume that it's true, then we have $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$ so $\frac{y}{2^x}=\frac{1}{3}$, and then $3y=2^x$. But what should I do next? How do I formally show that this statement is not true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $3y$ is an integer and $3y=2^x$, it follows that $2^x$ must be an integer as well. Then consider their prime factorizations. Since $y$ is also an integer, we must have that $3$ is a prime factor of $3y$. On the other hand, $2^x$ cannot have $3$ as a factor, so this is a contradiction.

Comment: thanks! Why $2^x$ cannot have $3$ as a factor. I understand it's true but how to show it formally?

Comment: Well for $2^x$ to be an integer, we either have $2^x=2^0=1$ in which case $3$ is not a factor, or we have $x>0$ in which case $2^x=\underbrace{2\cdot 2 \cdots 2}_{x}$. By the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, this prime factorization is unique. So there cannot be another prime factorization of $2^x$ which includes $3$ as a prime factor.

Answer (score 1):

We want to find integer solutions of $3y=2^x$ but there are none.